# $_REQUEST $_GET return undefined index while contain required value?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to access $_REQUEST value and assign it to variable

$id = $_REQUEST['ID'];

Also i tried it with isset but still no value is returned but when i use

print_r($_REQUEST);

i can see the desired value.

Here is the code.

This is where i am assigning $_REQUEST value to $id but i keep getting "Not Set".

```
<?php 
   require ("db.php");

   if(isset($_REQUEST["ID"])){

     $id= $_REQUEST["ID"];


 }
 echo "Not set";

 ?>
```

And this is the code from where i am calling above function. `<a href='edit.php?ID = $id'>Edit</a>`

```
<?php

       require "db.php";
       if(isset($_POST['show'])){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM person";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        $row = '';
        $id = "";
        echo "<table style = 'border =  1px solid, width: 350px;'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>ID</td>";
        echo "<td><b>FIRST</b></td>";
        echo "<td><b>LAST</b></td>";
        echo "<td><b>EMAIL</b></td>";
        echo "<td><b>TELEPHONE</b></td>";
        echo "<td><b>GENDER</b></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $id = $row['ID'];
            echo "<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row[1]."</td><td>".$row[2]."</td><td>".$row[3]."</td><td>".$row[4].
            "</td><td>".$row[5]."</td><td>"."<a href='edit.php?ID = $id'>Edit</a>"."</td></tr>";

        }
        echo "</table>";

        mysqli_close($connection);

       } 
     ?>
```

Comment: There should be no spaces between ID and equal sign in your URL: `ID=$id`

Comment: side notes: `border:1px solid; width:350px` | php can handle multi-line string literals, so your nine consecutive echos can shrink to one without loosing any readablity | matter of opinion: instead of concatenating the strings `string1 . string2` you can pass them as single parameters to echo like `echo '<tr><td>', $row[0], ...` | pass the database values to `htmlentities()` before print them "to" a html browser  to avoid "html injections" (is that a term?) | you're mixing positional result fields with named fields, `$row['ID']` vs `$row[0]`, imho named fields are better for maintainability

Comment: @barell: Thanks man its working now did't know space matter this much. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Add an else statement like this:

```
<?php 
require ("db.php");

if(isset($_REQUEST["ID"])){

 $id= $_REQUEST["ID"];


} else {
   echo "Not set";
}
?>
```

Comment: Not set part is working as i mentioned in my comments.